# fuelphp - Memcached Mysql

Tags: mysql, redis, memcached, fuelphp

I have read fuelphp documentation and i saw a topic about MySQL caching (mysql-server side), but nothing about memcached/redis builtin in fuelphp for mysql queries.

Someone has documentation about it ? Should be home made ?

Thanks for your help,
Regards,

Answer (score 1):

Database caching simply uses the Cache class. So if you have configured Cache to use a memcached or redis backend, that is what will be used.